# Generate elastic search AND query based upon list size i.e no. of AND's in the query will be based on no. of items in the list

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I have a list whose size is not fixed and can contain any no. of items.

Based on the number of items in the list, I have to generate an elastic search AND query to find the exact match of values.

For eg:

If my list contains 2 items : `['a', 'b']`, my elastic search query should look like this :

```
Q('term', field='a') & Q('term', field='b')
```

Similary, if my list contains 4 items : `['a', 'b','c','d']` ;my query will look like this :

```
Q('term', field='a') & Q('term', field='b') & Q('term', field='c') & Q('term', field='d')
```

What's the right approach to generate this kind of query based upon list size?

PS : I am using `elasticsearch_dsl` module's `Q` library to generate elastic search queries.

https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest is to examine what query the `&` operation produces and reproduce that directly. In this case: `Q('bool', must=[Q('term', field=x) for x in my_list])`

Answer (score 0):

My solution to perform the `&` operation was to produce `match` query for every item in the list.

```
must = []
for item in my_list:    
    must.append({'match': {'field_name': item}})
query = Q('bool', must=must)
```